# How can i activate --trace-asci debugging with curb/curl for ruby?

Tags: ruby, debugging, trace, curb

Standard curl supports command line option --trace-asci and --trace. Anyone any clues on how to set this option for a Curl::Easy object?

Comment: You know, I just tried using command line curl to access a few pages with the flags you are asking about.  It seems that they simply return the body of an HTML page.  Perhaps you may consider the Net::HTTP library instead?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Curb has a `verbose=` method which accepts a boolean.  Not sure if that duplicates the functionality that you are looking for, but it may be a good start.

Here is a link to the documentation: http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000093